# Why do you need (LinkedList)?

Tags: java, linked-list

So I have this one line of code here:

```
LinkedList<Integer> p = (LinkedList) obj.c.clone();
```

I was wondering why do you need the `(LinkedList)` part before `obj.c.clone()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: 
**You need type casting to get access to target class methods and fields.**

`Object` and `LinkedList` is same type hierarchy, so you can cast, otherwise You would get `ClassCastException` in Java. 
For more information about type casting, See this [link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/12/what-is-type-casting-in-java-class-interface-example.html).

Answer (score 3):

Method `Object.clone()` returns result of `Object` type. If you want use it as `LinkedList` you need explicit cast result to `LinkedList` type.

Answer (score 2):

`clone()` method returns an `Object`, so you have to cast it to `LinkedList`

Answer (score 2):

[LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) class implements [Java´s clonable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()). If you read the documentation on that concrete interface you find `clone` deffinition is:

```
protected Object clone()
```

That is, a reference to an `Object` object, in Java, to any object which is not an unwrapped basic type.

You need to cast the reference type to `LinkedList`´s in order to be able to use ("view") its methods/attributes not included in `Object` class definition.